# Wrong conversion using b64decode from the base64 library in python

Tags: python, base64

I'm trying to convert base64 encoded characters. All characters are converted fine except from "CQ==" and "Cg==". Those should be "\0x09" and "\0x0a", when using an online conversion tool (https://cryptii.com/pipes/binary-to-base64), but they're converted into "\t" and "\n". See code below:

```
import base64

a = "Bw=="
b = "CA=="
c = "CQ=="
d = "Cg=="
e = "Cw=="
f = "DA=="

print(base64.b64decode(a))
print(base64.b64decode(b))
print(base64.b64decode(c))
print(base64.b64decode(d))
print(base64.b64decode(e))
print(base64.b64decode(f))
```

and the output is the following:

```
b'\x07'
b'\x08'
b'\t'
b'\n'
b'\x0b'
b'\x0c'


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

I even tried first endoding "\0x09" into base64 and then decode it:

```
import base64

s = b'\x09'
s = base64.b64encode(s)

print(s)
print(base64.b64decode(s))
```

the result is:

```
b'CQ=='
b'\t'


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

I saw that endoding "\t" into base64 also gives "CQ==". Does "\t" and "\0x09" have the same encoding in base64 ?

```
import base64

s = b'\t'
s = base64.b64encode(s)

print(s)
print(base64.b64decode(s))
```

```
b'CQ=='
b'\t'


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

Comment: *Does "\t" and "\0x09" have the same encoding in base64 ?* -There is no magic in Base64 encoding. It encodes bytes. If the result in Base64 is the same, the original byte is the same. ['0x09' is the hex code for HT (horizontal tab) or \t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart). Try `print(b'\x09')` and you'll get "\t". Same story with \n and 0x0a (Linefeed) and many other codes.

Comment: I’ve found this answer in the meantime but thanks !